# Incorporating Django comments system into blog built with javascript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, django

I have a current site I built several years ago based on JavaScript and PHP and I would now like to incorporate a Django comments module (https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments) in it. However, I am very, very new to Django and am not quite sure how to incorporate Django in a preexisting JavaScript and PHP site. Looking at the modules I want to use, they each require attaching to an object, which is in Django. How would I go about connecting it to an object in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix languages like PHP and Python this but abstract out. They can share a database why not start there, or an API maybe?

Start by reading the Django docs I found them very helpful there is also a free online [Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html) read about models.

as a last resort there are options like this > 
http://www.scottgorlin.com/2009/07/embedding-django-in-php/
http://komunitasweb.com/2009/03/using-django-template-in-php/